# Eclipse is confused with Generics

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbi

I use JDBI in my project and I have a unit test like this:

```
@Test
public void testGetUser() {
    when(jdbi.withExtension(any(), any())).thenReturn(new ArrayList<>());
    List<User> users = dao.getUsers();
    assertTrue(users.isEmpty());
}
```

For reference, JDBI's `withExtension` method is declared like this:

```
public <R, E, X extends Exception> R withExtension(Class<E> extensionType, ExtensionCallback<R, E, X> callback)
```

And you can use it like this (extracted from JDBI docs):

```
// Jdbi implements your interface based on annotations
List<User> userNames = jdbi.withExtension(UserDao.class, dao -> {
    dao.createTable();

    dao.insertPositional(0, "Alice");
    dao.insertPositional(1, "Bob");
    dao.insertNamed(2, "Clarice");
    dao.insertBean(new User(3, "David"));

    return dao.listUsers();
});
```

The method `dao.getUsers()` doesn't do anything exceptional besides accessing the DB using JDBI and catches any exceptions and re-throws them as a custom exception that extends from `Exception`.

So far so good, all as expected, as I have:

- IntelliJ can understand the test and compile and runs it, no problems.
- I am using Maven and I can also run `mvn build` in the terminal without errors.

The problem:
In Eclipse, I have an error in `testGetUser()`: `Unhandled exception type Exception` in the line `when(jdbi.withExtension(any(), any())).thenReturn(new ArrayList<>());`.

I can't figure out why but my guess is that it is getting confused because of the Generics use.

I'd appreciate any ideas!